# Groovy char stream pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have the following code, from the `reader` stream i want to remove all occurances of `Command ran successfully.` Please help me suggest any solution

```
String ostream="license_all (47286) Command ran successfully. License a Command ran     successfully."
Reader reader = new StringReader(ostream)
for(c in reader)
{
print(c)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the *exact* form of `Command ran successfully.`, then you can do this:

```
reader.eachLine{ c ->
    println c.replaceAll('Command ran successfully.', '')
}
```

However, if you want to be more flexible, and replace it disregarding spaces and case, use this:

```
reader.eachLine{ c ->
    println c.replaceAll(/(?i)command\s+ran\s+successfully\s*\./, '')
}
```

Note, that in both instances, because we are looping over each *line*, it may be important to add back in the line break (`println` vs `print`).  Also, due looping over each line, this will not replace the string if it occurs split on more than one line.

Here's [a complete example](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/569001) which you can run and modify [on the Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/569001).  ([Link to original one with `for...in`.](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/568001))

Comment: Oh, I should also mention, it's more *Groovy* to use `reader.eachLine{ c -> }`, because it handles closing the stream automatically.  [Docs on `eachLine`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/Reader.html#eachLine%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

Comment: Yeah, I had posted the Groovy Web Console example before I thought of that.  I guess I'll go ahead and clean both of them up.  :-)